# search between two iso date in JSON mysql

Tags: mysql, json, database, mysql-json

Below is my JSON which is save in `response` column of mysql table

```
{
    "data": {
        "submit": false,
        "lastName": "abc",
        "firstName": "xys"
    },
    "metadata": {},
    "createDate": "2021-04-23T00:00:00+00:00"
}
```

Now I want to query between condition on that for that I try to write the below query

```
SELECT * FROM form_response WHERE DATE_FORMAT(response->'$.data.createDate', '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') BETWEEN "2021-04-22T00:00:00+00:00" AND "2021-04-23T00:00:00+00:00"
```

but I am getting blank response.

Any help appreciated

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT()` converts from date to string. I think you want `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I tried that but getting empty result for that as well `SELECT * FROM form_response WHERE STR_TO_DATE(response->'$.data.createDate', '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') BETWEEN "2021-04-22T00:00:00+00:00" AND "2021-04-23T00:00:00+00:00" `

Comment: it render `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM form_response WHERE DATE_FORMAT(SUBSTR(response->'$.createDate',2,CHAR_LENGTH(response->'$.createDate')-2), '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') BETWEEN "2021-04-22T00:00:00+00:00" AND "2021-04-23T00:00:00+00:00"

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM form_response 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(SUBSTR(response->'$.createDate',2,CHAR_LENGTH(response->'$.createDate')-2), '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') BETWEEN "2021-04-22T00:00:00Z" AND "2021-04-23T00:00:00Z"

Comment: Can you share your table structure too?

Answer (score 0):

`response->'$.data.createDate'` returns `null` already so nothing else matters after that. According to your data structure what you want is `response->'$.createDate'`. Also, `DATE_FORMAT()` converts from date to string. I think you want `STR_TO_DATE()`. Last but not least, the date format identifier you provide doesn't match the format used by data.

Don't treat your code as a black box. You can debug each processing step:

```
SELECT
    response->'$.createDate' AS string,
    STR_TO_DATE(response->'$.createDate', '"%Y-%m-%dT%T+00:00"') AS data
FROM form_response;
```

```
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| string                      | date                |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| "2021-04-23T00:00:00+00:00" | 2021-04-23 00:00:00 |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
```

In your case, you can simplify it further since you're using a standard date format that's recognised by MySQL:

```
SELECT
    response->'$.createDate' AS string,
    CAST(response->'$.createDate' AS DATETIME) AS date
FROM form_response;
```